# numpy.arange() cause no fill-function for data-type only when start=0

Tags: python, numpy

## Question

Please help understand why only `start=0` causes the error.

```
position_type = np.dtype([
    ('x', np.int32),
    ('y', np.int32)
])
color_type = np.dtype([
    ('r', np.int32),
    ('g', np.int32),
    ('b', np.int32)    
])
pixel_type = np.dtype([
    ('position', position_type),
    ('color', color_type)
])

print(np.arange(start=-1, stop=-3, step=-1, dtype=pixel_type))
print(np.arange(start=1, stop=3, step=1, dtype=pixel_type))

print(np.arange(start=0, stop=3, step=1, dtype=pixel_type))    # <--- Error
---
[((-1, -1), (-1, -1, -1)) ((-2, -2), (-2, -2, -2))]
[((1, 1), (1, 1, 1)) ((2, 2), (2, 2, 2))]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-318cf1206b0a> in <module>
     16 print(np.arange(start=1, stop=3, step=1, dtype=pixel_type))
     17 
---> 18 print(np.arange(start=0, stop=3, step=1, dtype=pixel_type))

ValueError: no fill-function for data-type.
```

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.arange` doesn't support structured dtypes. Your first two tests happen to do what you expected pretty much by fluke. Your `start=0` example fails not because that `start` value is special, but because that's the only case where the computed length of the output is greater than 2.

Internally, `numpy.arange` computes an output length, allocates an array of that length, sets the first two elements, then calls a "fill" function for the array's dtype to set the remaining elements. Structured dtypes have no fill function, so they raise an exception at this step. However, if the computed output length is 2, `arange` skips calling the fill function. You can see all this in the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.4/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L3228).

Answer (score 0):

```
In [185]: position_type = np.dtype([
     ...:     ('x', np.int32),
     ...:     ('y', np.int32)
     ...: ])
     ...: color_type = np.dtype([
     ...:     ('r', np.int32),
     ...:     ('g', np.int32),
     ...:     ('b', np.int32)
     ...: ])
     ...: pixel_type = np.dtype([
     ...:     ('position', position_type),
     ...:     ('color', color_type)
     ...: ])
```

The aranges construction simple numeric sequence:

```
In [186]: np.arange(-1,-3, -1)
Out[186]: array([-1, -2])
In [187]: np.arange(0,-3, -1)
Out[187]: array([ 0, -1, -2])
In [188]: np.arange(0,3, 1)
Out[188]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

Casting to `pixel_type`.  Note that it simply assigns that same number to each field of a record.

```
In [189]: np.arange(-1,-3, -1).astype(pixel_type)
Out[189]: 
array([((-1, -1), (-1, -1, -1)), ((-2, -2), (-2, -2, -2))],
      dtype=[('position', [('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4')]), ('color', [('r', '<i4'), ('g', '<i4'), ('b', '<i4')])])

In [190]: np.arange(0,-3, -1).astype(pixel_type)
Out[190]: 
array([(( 0,  0), ( 0,  0,  0)), ((-1, -1), (-1, -1, -1)),
       ((-2, -2), (-2, -2, -2))],
      dtype=[('position', [('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4')]), ('color', [('r', '<i4'), ('g', '<i4'), ('b', '<i4')])])

In [191]: np.arange(0,3, 1).astype(pixel_type)
Out[191]: 
array([((0, 0), (0, 0, 0)), ((1, 1), (1, 1, 1)), ((2, 2), (2, 2, 2))],
      dtype=[('position', [('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4')]), ('color', [('r', '<i4'), ('g', '<i4'), ('b', '<i4')])])
```

Putting the dtype in the arange:

Same as casting after:

```
In [192]: np.arange(-1,-3, -1, dtype=pixel_type)
Out[192]: 
array([((-1, -1), (-1, -1, -1)), ((-2, -2), (-2, -2, -2))],
      dtype=[('position', [('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4')]), ('color', [('r', '<i4'), ('g', '<i4'), ('b', '<i4')])])
```

Your problem case:

```
In [193]: np.arange(0,3, 1, dtype=pixel_type)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-193-a327f2fc066d>", line 1, in <module>
    np.arange(0,3, 1, dtype=pixel_type)
ValueError: no fill-function for data-type.
```

`arange` is a compiled function, so we don't (readily) know what it is doing.  I commented that `numpy` can't do math across the fields of a compound dtype.  I don't know what's different between the `astype` case and including the dtype in `arange` call.   Nothing is documented.

---

Another 2 element case that works:

```
In [215]: np.arange(0,2, dtype=pixel_type)
Out[215]: 
array([((0, 0), (0, 0, 0)), ((1, 1), (1, 1, 1))],
      dtype=[('position', [('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4')]), ('color', [('r', '<i4'), ('g', '<i4'), ('b', '<i4')])])
```